# What does this "Common" pin mean on this multiport switch?

Tags: pcb-design, rf, switches

I have this [RF switch 87104C, T24 Option](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/assets/7018-06804/technical-overviews/5091-3366.pdf)

Page 6 describes the switch indicators:

> The circuitry consists of a common which can be connected to an output corresponding to each RF path. If multiple RF paths are engaged, the position indicator corresponding to each closed RF path will be connected to common

[image]

I understand this "common" pin to be basically ground (return path) for those indicators, or am I missing something?

If it really  is ground, should I separate this GND from main ground (power source ground, chasis ground) by adding some ferrites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of those switches are optically isolated solid state relays. The isolation provided means you can connect the pins how you see fit (whilst conforming to the spec of the isolation and relays)

You could connect the common to GND if you want the switched signals to be pulled down to GND when selected - e.g. connecting the "PATH" pins to the cathode of an LED with anode to a positive supply voltage.

You could also connect the common to some supply voltage if you want the switched signals to be pulled up to that voltage when selected - e.g. if the "PATH" pins were connected to say the anode of an LED, with the cathodes to GND.

You are free to choose where you connect the signal - much like with any xPST (DPST, 3PST, etc) type switch.

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> *as I understand this "common" pin is basically ground (return path)
> for those indicators or I'm missing something*

It can be connected to a logic supply if you want. The switches in the diagram are in fact solid-state relays and, they are compatible with AC or DC as per the voltage and current limits below: -

[image]

Regarding "those indicators"; they are solid-state relays and not indicators. You have to supply the external indicators that can be activated by the solid-state relays inside the device.

> *If it really is ground, should I separate this GND from main ground
> (power source ground, chassis ground) by adding some ferrites?*

There's no reason to presume you'll need some form of ferrite in this lines whether they are grounded or at some other voltage within the limits of the table above. There may be other reasons to add ferrites but they won't be needed to prevent the device from operating correctly.

Comment: thank you so much!